# Option pricing with binomial trees

Tags: probability, finance

Background:
In an exercise about option pricing using binomial trees, the portfolio is riskless if

$$ S_{0u} \Delta - f_u = S_{0d} \Delta - f_d $$

So

$$ \Delta = \frac{f_u - f_d}{S_0(u-d)} $$

represents the amount of underlying I have to buy (if $\Delta >0$) or to sell (if $\Delta <0$).

Let's define a value p s.t.

$$p = \frac{e^{rT}-d}{u-d}$$

So, the price $f$ is

$$f = e^{rT}(pf_u + (1-p)f_d)$$

where $f_u$ is the option payoff value in case of "up" (growing value according to a factor $u>1$) and $f_d$ is the

option payoff value in case of "down" (decreasing value according to a factor $0<d<1$).

The question:

Prove that probability $0\leq p \leq 1$.

My attempt, proof with reductio ad absurdum:

Let's start from $p < 0$

$$\frac{e^{rT}-d}{u-d} < 0$$

But $u-d>0$ so

$$ e^{rT}-d < 0$$

id est

$$ e^{rT}<d $$

$$rT<\ln d$$

and we know that $\ln d<0$, because $0<d<1$

But $T>0$ surely because it's a time

and $r$ would become $<0$, but this is not possible because it's an interest rate ($0\leq r\leq 1$).

Up to now, proved that $p < 0$ is not possible.

But it's the round to show that $p>1$ is not possible.

With similar passages I obtain

$$rT>\ln d$$

with $\ln d<0$

But this inequality is possible, so I'm stuck.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Your multiplication is wrong. 

$\frac{e^{rt}-d}{u-d}>1$ implies $e^{rt}>u$.

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the definition of $p$ that $0\leq p\leq 1$ is equivalent to $d\leq e^{rT}\leq u$.

Next, note that if either $e^{rT}<d$ or $e^{rT}>u$ there will be an arbitrage opportunity. In the first case the "risky" asset is guaranteed to grow in value more quickly than the "risk-free" asset, and in the second case it is guaranteed to grow more slowly. In both cases we could set up a portfolio having value zero at time zero which is guaranteed to have a positive value at time $T$.

So under the assumption that there are no arbitrage opportunities, we must have $d\leq e^{rT}\leq u$.